# replace the dialog "Turn on Location Services to allow app to determine your location services" with custom alertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

is there a way to change the above alertview or add a button to the same alertview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't change any of Apple's privacy access alerts like alerts while accessing Location, Addressbook, Camera Album.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to change this dialog - it's a standard dialog for good reason, as if a custom dialog could be used it would be trivial to lie to the user regarding what they were confirming.